# Android strings fallback shows different behaviour for different locale

Tags: android, locale, android-resources

I have my app localisation done where app support

> en, en-AU, en-CA, en-TH, en-US

App have a string that is present in *default, en-AU, en-TH strings.xml* files. Now when user with locale US runs the app, string is picked from default strings file (which is expected as string is not present in *en-US*) but when user with locale CA runs the app, string is picked from *en-AU* (Android 10,11,12) and from *en-TH* (Android 13).

Expectation is that strings should be picked from default if not present in locale specific strings.xml.
Everything works fine if i have string in all strings file, it picks from respective strings file as per locale selected.
Am i missing something here. Already tried with new project.

P.S:- Setting Locale in MainActivity

```
        val conf: Configuration = res.configuration
        conf.locale = Locale("en","US") //CA for canada
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.displayMetrics)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should include both `values` (default) and `values-en` directories in your project, even if it means some string duplication.

The **default** values directory should be considered a last resort for the Android operating system when it comes to determining the language of your app's strings. This is because the OS can't be certain whether the strings in this directory are written in English or another language.

Prioritizing the **en-AU** or **en-TH** directories over the **default** values directory is a logical choice in my opinion. While these languages may not perfectly match the user's preferred language, they should still be understandable enough for user.

Once you've added the **values-en** directory to your Android app, it becomes the default fallback when a specific language (en-AU, en-CA, en-TH, en-US) is missing.

You can read more about language and locale resolution [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support)

Comment: Prioritizing the en-AU or en-TH directories over the default values directory is a logical choice in my opinion. -> I totally agree with this but in case of US locale it is falling back to values-en first and then to default directly where as for en-CA it fallback to values-en and then to child english first and then to default

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one,

```
conf.locale = Locale("en")
```

remove "US" if you want the default string.

Comment: in this scenario it will always pick from default, some strings need need to be picked from specific file